# React Native Change List background color onPress

Tags: typescript, list, react-native

I want to change the background color of the only Item I select from the list

currently I am able to change the background color by assigning the color depending on a prop

```
activeColor = props.name === name ? 'red' : 'grey';
```

but when I select item from the list it changes the background color and saves it

Here is my attempt
[Snack Link](https://snack.expo.dev/@qsw70/biased-coffee) "run it on Android"

Answer (score 0):

i have changed the structure create the state for selected Item in the paraent component and pass it as a prop for the child component along with setState method

snack Link: https://snack.expo.dev/@ashwith00/biased-coffee

code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Example from './components/AssetExample';

let data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Card 1',
    city: 'London',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Card 2',
    city: 'London 2',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Card 3',
    city: 'London 3',
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    title: 'Card 4',
    city: 'London 4',
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    title: 'Card 5',
    city: 'London 5',
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <Example
          title={item.title}
          name={item.city}
          key={item.id}
          {...{ selectedItem, setSelectedItem }}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 80,
  },
});


import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export type ExampleProps = {
  title: string,
  name: string,
  selectedItem: any,
  setSelectedItem: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>,
};
let activeColor: string;
const Example = (props: ExampleProps) => {
  const { selectedItem, setSelectedItem } = props;

  const activeColor = React.useMemo(
    () => (props.name === selectedItem ? 'red' : 'grey'),
    [props.name, selectedItem]
  );

  const onPlay = async () => {
    setSelectedItem(props.name);
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPlay}>
      <View style={[styles.row, { backgroundColor: activeColor }]}>
        <View style={[styles.cell, { flex: 1 }]}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.name}>{props.name}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default Example;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  cell: {
    padding: 16,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  name: {
    color: 'black',
  },
  title: {
    color: 'black',
  },
});
```

Comment: can you please explain what this piece of code does?  `{...{ selectedItem, setSelectedItem }}`

Comment: in your code you handle the setState inside the chid component so once you click the child you wont be able to unselect it, thats why you ones the item background becomes red it wont change back, so you have to create it in the parent and ones item is press set that item as selected so when other item is pressed we are setting it as the selected item, so the backgroundColor for that item will change to red and previous selected item will unselect

Answer (score 0):

You must manage the state globally, or through the parent component in this case. Your code does not work because one instance of the child component "AssetExample.js" has no access to the state of another "AssetExample.js" child component.

I have made step by step instructions on how to modify your example code to achieve what you want. I believe it may help you understand how it should work if you follow them in steps.

---

#### 1. Add two more Props in "AssetExample.js".

We want to manage the child component state that is dependent on the parent component (one child component of the parent causes another child component to change).

Therefore, the logic of "clicking" the component and updating the "isSelected" state should be managed by the parent component. Also, pass the prop "isSelected" for the child component to re-render based on its "selected" state (and change the background color).

```
export type ExampleProps = {
  title: string,
  name: string,
  onPress: ()=>{}, // <-- Implement this in the parent component
  isSelected: boolean, // <-- Simple boolean value to determine the background color
};
```

#### 2. Determine background color based on "isSelected" prop in "AssetExample.js"

isSelected will be updated by the parent component ("App.js"). When it does, it will cause the child component ("AssetExample.js") to re-render. The background color (activeColor variable) will be determined based on the "isSelected" value.

```
  activeColor = props.isSelected ? 'red' : 'grey';
```

#### 3. Change the onPress method to props.onPress in "AssetExample.js"

- Note that it's props.onPress NOT props.onPress()

```
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>
      ...
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

#### 4. In "App.js", add state to track which item has been selected.

We use the "useState" hook to track which item is selected from the parent component.

```
const [selectedName, setSelectedName] = React.useState()
```

#### 5. In "App.js", add the following props to the <Example /> component

Pass the props to the child component.

```
<Example 
  title={item.title} 
  name={item.city} 
  key={item.id} 
  onPress={() => setSelectedName(item.city)} // <-- Add this
  isSelected={item.city===selectedName} // <-- Add this
/>
```

---

## Full Code w/o data&styles - "App.js"

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Example from './components/AssetExample';

let data = [...]; // REMOVED for readability

export default function App() {

  const [selectedName, setSelectedName] = React.useState() // <-- Add this

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {
        data.map((item) => (
          <Example 
            title={item.title} 
            name={item.city} 
            key={item.id} 
            onPress={() => setSelectedName(item.city)} // <-- Add this
            isSelected={item.city===selectedName} // <-- Add this
          />
        ))
      }
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ ... }); // REMOVED for readability
```

---

## Full Code - "AssetExample.js"

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export type ExampleProps = {
  title: string,
  name: string,
  onPress: ()=>{}, // Add this
  isSelected: boolean, // Add this
};
let activeColor: string;
const Example = (props: ExampleProps) => {
  // You can remove this
  // const [name, setName] = useState();
  
  activeColor = props.isSelected ? 'red' : 'grey';  // Change this

  // You can remove this
  // const onPlay = async () => { 
  //   setName(props.name);
  // };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}> // Change this
      <View style={[styles.row, { backgroundColor: activeColor }]}>
        <View style={[styles.cell, { flex: 1 }]}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.name}>{props.name}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default Example;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ ... }); // REMOVED for readability
```

Comment: really appreciate the explanation